# Hyperlink containing %

Tags: links, cv

I'm trying to include a hyperlink in my CV in TeX that contains the character "%", which results in TeX making the part of the hyperlink following % as comments. Advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a minimal but compilable example of what you are trying to do. How are you typing hyperlinks in your document? Which package do you use for that?

Comment: Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211495/hyperlink-containing%}
\end{document}` work for you?

Comment: I'm using \include{structure} which has various commands starting with \usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry} % Adjusts the margins

\usepackage{multicol} %

Comment: The command I'm having trouble with is \href. I just tried \usepackage{hyperref} \url you suggested, but it didn't work

Comment: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211495/hyperlink-containing%}{some text} with `hyperref` works for me.

Comment: I tried your links and they did not work for me. It must be due to the different package I'm using. It is the CV package I downloaded from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/cies-resume-cv

Comment: Fantastic: the file `structure.tex` (which is part of your cv template) defines a macro `\bull`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `%` in the first argument (the link destination) and `\%` in the second (which is typeset).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{http://example.com/test%281%29.html}{http://example.com/test\%281\%29.html}
\end{document}
```

Comment: % still making the rest as a comment, what to do?

Comment: @AlFagera --- the above example works for me. I suggest you ask a new question, because your case must be different.